# contradiction to commutative tensor product.

Tags: vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I am studying now abstract algebra and my professor is always assuming that we have a commutative ring with unity and she told us that the tensor product is commutative. But I am now was trying to solve the following problem:

Let $k$ be a field and $B = k[x,y].$ Define $R-$modules $J = (x,y), N = J/J^2$ and $M = J \otimes_B J.$

Define $m \in M$ by $m = x \otimes y - y \otimes x.$ Show that $m \neq 0$

And this was the answer given to me by @Eric Wofsey:

It is not correct that $x \otimes y - y \otimes x = (x-y) \otimes (y-x)$ in this case.  Indeed, note that $N$ is just a 2-dimensional vector space over $B/J\cong k$, with $\{x,y\}$ as a basis.  So, $N\otimes_B N=N\otimes_{B/J} N$ is just a tensor product of vector spaces and so it is 4-dimensional with $\{x\otimes x,x\otimes y,y\otimes x,y\otimes y\}$ as a basis.  This shows that $x \otimes y - y \otimes x \neq (x-y) \otimes (y-x)$, but it also just directly shows that $x\otimes y-y\otimes x$ is nonzero.

**My question is:**

Why the tensor product does not commute in this case? i.e., why  this element $x\otimes y$ from the basis is not considered the same as this element $y\otimes x$?

Comment: Why would you think that $x\otimes y = y \otimes x$? Really I don't get it why you should even believe that holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "tensor product is commutative" most probably refers to the fact that for any modules $M$ and $N$ there exists an isomorphism between $M\otimes N$ and $N\otimes M$ defined by $m\otimes n\mapsto n\otimes m$. One usually says that tensor product of *modules* (not their *elements*) is commutative up to an isomorphism. Note that it says nothing about $m\otimes n$ and $n\otimes m$ being actually *equal* (in fact, they even belong to different modules, namely $M\otimes N$ and $N\otimes M$, respectively).

Comment: That makes complete sense. thank you!